When is $\pi_{k}(X_{p}^{\wedge})$ not isomorphic to the p-completion of the group $\pi_{k}(X)$?
Let $X$ be a spectrum, $p$ a prime, we denote the $p$-completion of $X$ as
$X_{p}^{\wedge}$, i.e. the Bousfield localization $L_{\mathbb{S}/p}X$. This $p$-completion of spectra is quite important in chromatic homotopy theory, if the property presented here is true for all spectra, then studying the homotopy groups of them is quite easy.
We know that
when $\pi_{k}(X)$ is finitely generated for every degree, then $\pi_{k}(X_{p}^{\wedge}) 
\cong (\pi_{k}(X))_{p}^{\wedge}$. This is shown in Bousfield's paper: THE LOCALIZATION OF SPECTRA WITH RESPECT
TO HOMOLOGY, 1997, Prop.2.5. So do we have some counterexamples to
this isomorphism?

Sure. In general the homotopy groups of $X_p^\wedge$ sit in a short exact sequence
$$
    0 \to \operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z} / p^\infty, \pi_* X) \to \pi_* X_p^\wedge \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z} / p^\infty, \pi_{* - 1} X) \to 0
$$
so you can consider, say, $X = H \mathbb{Z} / p^\infty$; then $\pi_1 (H \mathbb{Z} / p^\infty)_p^\wedge \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z} / p^\infty, \mathbb{Z} / p^\infty) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \neq 0$ but obviously $\pi_1 H \mathbb{Z} / p^\infty = 0$.

Thanks a lot for your answer!
